# Merge sort Algorithm isn't fully merging. The right side of the array isn't merging with the left side

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

So I am trying to implement a MergeSort algorithm on an array.

My unsorted array is[3, -5, -10, 22, -100, 1]

However, when executed it is [-5, -10, 3, 22, -100, 1]

Clearly, the right side of the array position 4 and 5 aren't clearly merging.

I was thinking that maybe I haven't partitioned the array fully and that is why it isn't merging correctly.

Below is my mergeSort code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int [] arr = {3, -5, -10, 22, -100, 1};
    System.out.println("unsorted array is" +Arrays.toString(arr));

    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length);

    System.out.println("it is now merged "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
}


public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(end -start < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (start + end)/2;

    //merge the left side of array
    mergeSort(arr, start, mid);

    //merge the right side of the array
    mergeSort(arr,mid +1, end);

    merge(arr, start, mid, end);
}

public static void merge(int [] arr, int start, int mid, int end) {

    //checking
    if(arr[mid -1] <= arr[mid]) {
        return;
    }

    if(start <= end && mid >= start && mid <= end) {

    //creating temporary array
    int [] temp = new int[end -start + 1];

    //initialising values
    int i = start;
    int j = mid;
    int tempIndex = 0;

    while(i < mid && j < end + 1) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
            temp[tempIndex] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }

        else {
            temp[tempIndex] = arr[i];
            i ++;
        }
        tempIndex ++;
    }

    //exit while loop

    if(i < mid) {
        //if that is true then loop
        for(; i< mid; i++) {
            temp[tempIndex] = arr[i];
            tempIndex ++;
        }
    }

    else {
        for(;j < end +1; j++) {
            temp[tempIndex] = arr[j];
            tempIndex ++;
        }
    }

    //copy back into array

    for (int k = start;k <= end; k++) {
        arr[k] = temp[k-start];
    }

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct two things:
In main:

```
mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length);
```

to:

```
mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
```

and in mergeSort method

```
//merge the right side of the array
mergeSort(arr, mid+1, end);
```

to:

```
//merge the right side of the array
mergeSort(arr, mid, end);
```

The thing is that you always provide more elements that array has (elements are counted from 0 to arr.length-1) and than you omit last divide in recursive tree when elements in dividing array are even. (So you skip merge of right part of array)

Comment: Here is good example of merge sort: 
[link](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Java/blob/master/Sorts/src/sort/MergeSort.java)